# DataSet.Merge - Merge typed DataSet/DataTable to another DataSet and work with it

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset, ado.net

I asked this question already on GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/issues/160 and
Microsoft Q&A and haven't get an answer until now. I hope the big stackoverflow community can help me :)

This was my initial question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f698731-db76-4eb0-a86d-d77d6a852644/datasetmerge-merge-typed-dataset-to-another-and-work-with-it?forum=adodotnetdataset#c53484c0-c6a1-4b8c-926f-f3e9ec2bc966

I have two DataSets which each one has one DataTable.
Now I have this code for example:

```
     MainSet mainSet = new MainSet();

     SubSet subSet = new SubSet();

     subSet.SubTable.AddSubTableRow("test1", "test12", "test13");
     subSet.SubTable.AddSubTableRow("test2", "test22", "test13");
     subSet.SubTable.AddSubTableRow("test3", "test32", "test33").SetDataColumn3Null();

     subSet.AcceptChanges();

     mainSet.Merge(subSet.SubTable);          

     if(mainSet.Tables["SubTable"] is SubSet.SubTableDataTable subSetTable)
     {    
         var emptyRows = subSetTable.Where(row => row.IsDataColumn3Null()).ToArray();

         if (emptyRows.Any())
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Found empty rows.");
         }
     }
```

One answer to a requestion of the old post: Yes we use a middle tier architecture and need to merge the second DataSet to the "MainSet" because the second DataSet is reused by other BusinessRules again....

The Cast isn't the problem, this works correct. But then the call like "row.IsDataColumn3Null()" doesn't work, because I get an exception like "DataColumn3 does not belongs to table SubTable".

Now I know a little bit why I get this exception because I studied the .NET Code for this.
But I don't know the reason why this is implemented in this way and I hope I reach someone from the ADO.NET Team who can give me an answer.

The reason why I get this exception is because the CheckColumn Method of the DataRow checks the Table of the Row with the Table of the Column if they are equal. But the Table of the column is null after the Merge.
What is Merge doing?

In a short way: the internal Clone(DataSet dataSet) Method from DataTable is called during the Merge-Process.
An instance of SubTable is created via the Activator.CreateInstance. ... This is why the cast works correct
After that it checks if columns available and called the Reset() Method of the new instance. In this moment all columns of the table are removed. And the reference to the datacolumn is loosing the table. Later in CloneTo(...) Method from DataTable, the columns of the original table are add again.
I think they do this because you can manipulate columns or add columns to a table. With only creating an instance you don't have had these changes....

But now I look at the designer file generated in the code and find the "InitVars" method. This method does what I need. But because the method is Internal, I can't call this method from another solution where I just add a reference to the dll where my DataSet is defined.

```
     [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
     [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "16.0.0.0")]
     internal void InitVars() {
         this.columnDataColumn3 = base.Columns["DataColumn3"];
         this.columnDataColumn2 = base.Columns["DataColumn2"];
         this.columnDataColumn1 = base.Columns["DataColumn1"];
     }
```

This code is assigning the base Column to the member this.columnDataColumn3 and all of my code above is would be working when I call InitVars directly after the cast.
But now the question to the developers of the DataTable ( :) ) Why isn't InitVars a virtual method in DataTable and calling this after the merge (after adding the columns again) ?

Or another solution that would be work:

The code generator creating this code for DataColumn3Column (which is using in method like IsDataColumn3Null() etc.)

```
     public global::System.Data.DataColumn DataColumn3Column {
         get {
             return this.columnDataColumn3;
         }
     }
```

Why isn't this code generated:

```
public global::System.Data.DataColumn DataColumn3Column { get { return base.Columns["DataColumn3"]; } }
```

Could this be a performance issue?

With kind regards
Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem. (For those playing at home, to reproduce the problem, "MainSet" should not contain a table called "SubTable" at design time).
One workaround is to call the protected InitVars via reflection.
e.g. :

```
    if (main.Tables["SubTable"] is SubSet.SubTableDataTable subSetTable)
    {
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = subSetTable.GetType().GetMethod("InitVars", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (mi == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("could not get InitVars method info");

        mi.Invoke(subSetTable, null);  // call InitVars via reflection

        var emptyRows = subSetTable.Where(row => row.IsDataColumn3Null()).ToArray();
```

I'm actually surprised that:

```
if (main.Tables["SubTable"] is SubSet.SubTableDataTable subSetTable)
```

returns true, as main is of the typed dataset: MainSet, and Subset.SubTableDataTable is defined in another typed dataset.
Normally, for this sort of code, I would expect that the MainSet typed dataset also have the SubSet datatable defined at design time.
Then after the merge, you can reference main.SubTable as a MainSet.SubTableDataTable, and it works properly, without having to call InitVars. But I guess this approach may not suit your requirements.

Comment: if (main.Tables["SubTable"] is SubSet.SubTableDataTable subSetTable) is true because they do a copy of a special type and not untyped. (look at the source code). There must be a reason why they don't call InitVars after the Merge automatically. Yes we can't add all possible "sub-tables" to the main set.